# Create temporary object as an argument on the stack

Tags: c++, heap-memory, stack-memory

In any programming language without pointers with garbage collector I can do

```
DrawLine(new Vector(0, 0), new Vector(100, 100));
```

But in C++ we can't if `DrawLine` is not responsible for deleting its arguments, so the shortest way to invoke `DrawLine` with two vectors `(0,0)` and `(100,100)` is:

```
Vector v(0, 0);
Vector w(100, 100);
DrawLine(v, w);
```

Is there a way to make this into a single statement? Especially if `v` and `w` are just arguments to that single function and no other function uses it, it seems a bit verbose. Why can't I just do something like:

```
DrawLine(Vector(0, 0), Vector(100, 100));
```

Comment: "Why can't I just do something like: `DrawLine(Vector(0, 0), Vector(100, 100));`" Because `DrawLine` is foolish enough to require lvalues or the compiler is broken?

Comment: The line [do works](https://ideone.com/isPOZG). Another case that *you* can't do that is that it is banned in your coding conventions.

Comment: @MikeCAT, Thank you! You are right, it does compile!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why can't I just do something like:
>
> ```
> DrawLine(Vector(0, 0), Vector(100, 100));
> ```

You're trying to pass temporary variables as argument. You can do it in 3 cases.

1. If `DrawLine` takes parameters passed by const reference:

   `void DrawLine(const Vector& v1, const Vector& v2);`
2. If `Vector` could be copied, and `DrawLine` takes parameters passed by value:

   `void DrawLine(Vector v1, Vector v2);`
3. If `Vector` could be moved, and `DrawLine` takes parameters passed by rvalue reference:

   `void DrawLine(Vector&& v1, Vector&& v2);`

The only failing case is passing parameters by non-const reference, since temporary variable couldn't be bound to it.

```
void DrawLine(Vector& v1, Vector& v2);
```