# Why can not the operator<< for test2 + test3 be overloaded?

Tags: c++, class, c++11, operator-overloading, friend-function

I try to overload the `operator<<`, but there is a warning that I cannot overload it. I can overload this operator as follows:

```
std::cout << test4 << std::endl;
```

But I can not overload it as follows:

```
std::cout << test2 + test3 << std::endl;
```

My main code is:

```
Stonewt test2(2, 8, Stonewt::STONE);
std::cout << "test2: " << test2 << std::endl;

Stonewt test3(2, 3, Stonewt::POUNDS);

std::cout << "test3: " << test3 << std::endl;

Stonewt test4 = test2 + test3;
std::cout << test4 << std::endl;         // operator << can overload
std::cout << test2 + test3 << std::endl; // operator << cannot overload
```

Below is the `friend` function

```
std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& os, Stonewt& a)
{
    if (a.format == Stonewt::STONE)
    {
        os << "stone format" << '\n';
        os << a.stone << " stones " << a.pound << " pounds" << '\n';
    }
    else if (a.format == Stonewt::POUNDS)
    {
        os << "pounds format" << '\n';
        os << a.pounds << " pounds" << '\n';
    }
    else
        os << "not valdid" << '\n';
    return os;
}
```

Comment: The operation `test2+test3` results in a *temporary* object, an *rvalue* which as mentioned can't be bound by non-constant references.

Comment: This error has nothing to with operator overloading, it's just about the rule saying you can't bind a non-const reference to a temporary. You would have got the same problem even if you were just writing regular functions instead of operator overloading.

Comment: @Slava I think even Microsoft have moved on from that issue. Now about that friendly g++ compiler that thinks `int a[n];` is OK for variable `n`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `test2+test3` results a temporary `Stonewt` object(*rvalue*) which can not be bound to a `non-const` reference(*lvalue*: i.e. `Stonewt &a`),rather with a `const` qualified *lvalue* reference. Therefore change the non-member function to:

```
std::ostream & operator <<(std::ostream &os, const Stonewt &a)
//                                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
{
      // ....
      return os;
}
```

---

Further readings:

- [Why can't pass temporary object as reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27463785/cant-pass-temporary-object-as-reference)
- [Why can temporary objects be bound to const reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49141435/why-can-temporary-objects-be-bound-to-const-reference)
- [How come a non-const reference cannot bind to a temporary object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565600/how-come-a-non-const-reference-cannot-bind-to-a-temporary-object)

Answer (score 0):

This is not the operator<< not working for test2 + test3. It is missing an operator+.

You need to overload the operator+ so the 'test2 + test3' will work. The overload of operator<< is working but the compiler has no idea what to do when it encounters 'test2 + test3', thus issuing the assumed error.